# How do I dynamically change names in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

how do I dynamically change icons in the app_icon in this program. I am trying to get notified on my desktop every 10 minutes with the price of stocks in my tick_list.This program works fine but I have different icon files in icons folder and it has all the icon files stored for each symbol in tick_list i.e nvda.ico, tsla.ico, fb.ico. Also, I would like to add the symbol name in the message. Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from plyer import notification
import time


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
}

first_ticker = "https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol="
last_ticker = "&qsearchterm="
tick_list = ["nvda", "tsla", "fb"]
stockurl_list = ["".join([first_ticker, tick, last_ticker, tick]) for tick in tick_list]


def stock_tracker(stockurl):
    page = requests.get(stockurl, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

    table = soup.find("table", class_="quote-horizontal regular")

    price = table.find("span", class_="last original").get_text()
    actual_price = float(price)
    notification.notify(
        title="Stock Price alert",
        message=f"Stock price: {actual_price}",
        app_icon=r"C:\Users\\VSCode\Projects\StockTrackerAlert\icons\nvda.ico",
        timeout=5,
    )
    time.sleep(3)

for stockurl in stockurl_list:
    stock_tracker(stockurl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, expand your definition of stock_tracker:

```py
def stock_tracker(stockurl, symbol):
```

Then use the symbol in app_icon, like that:

```py
app_icon=r"C:\Users\\VSCode\Projects\StockTrackerAlert\icons\{}.ico".format(symbol),
```

and then make sure you include symbol in your iteration, and you pass it to the function call:

```py
for stockurl, symbol in zip(stockurl_list, tick_list):
    stock_tracker(stockurl, symbol)
```

So your entire code is:

```py
def stock_tracker(stockurl, symbol):
    page = requests.get(stockurl, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

    table = soup.find("table", class_="quote-horizontal regular")

    price = table.find("span", class_="last original").get_text()
    actual_price = float(price)
    notification.notify(
        title="Stock Price alert",
        message=f"Stock price: {actual_price}",
        app_icon=r"C:\Users\\VSCode\Projects\StockTrackerAlert\icons\{}.ico".format(symbol),
        timeout=5,
    )
    time.sleep(3)

for stockurl, symbol in zip(stockurl_list, tick_list):
    stock_tracker(stockurl, symbol)
```